# Show an Pdf file in Silverlight in Webbrowser control has problems in IIS

Tags: silverlight, security, iis, pdf, webbrowser-control

I have created a Silverlight application which creates Pdf's and shows pdf's.
On my developemt environment is works fine, however on the server it breaks. I exprect these are security issues.
I show Pdf's using an URL. When I copy the URL and pass this directly in a browser (Google and Internet explorer)) it shows de Pdf as expected. However, my Webbrowser control in Silverlight shows only an icon, no pdf. The same pdf is visible in my development environment in the webbrowser control.
On the server I granted full access to everyone on the specified directory incl subdirectories. Unfortunatly, this does not solve it. Besides that it is not done ofcourse ;-)

Can anybody help me out?
I expect that I am looking in the wrong direction.

Kind regards,
André

Answer (score 0):

If your silverlight application creates the PDF it will be created on the computer browsing to your site. If you refer to a location on your server with the url it will not be found.
When testing this in your development environment it will succeed since you remain on the same machine.

Comment: Hi Jeroen,I create the pdf on the server, not on my local machine. I do this using a Silevrlight-enabled webservice.

Comment: Sorry, pushed the button too soon...  URL like http://yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:xxxx/ClientBin/Documents/35a7300d-eac4-436c-a4a5-e51f890f3ed1.Pdf

Answer (score 0):

PDF is a binary format that will be downloaded via the URL that u have defined.  However once it is client side the browser needs a program to render it.  The icon is telling you that the browser in the web control does not know what program to use to render it. I would create an HTML page with the appropriate links to render it, but that is on the edge of my knowledge.

Comment: Hi codputer, first thank you for taking the time to help me out. If it is correct what you suggest, how can I interpret that. The webbrowser control shoud know as well in development as in the client that it can show Pdf. Or can it be different?

Comment: If you browse from your computer using the same URL that you used in hte web control - does it display the PDF? My thought is that it would as your full client brower has suffficent trust to decode the PDF suffice to an Adobe reader program.  however, the Web Control is within a sandbox, and likely does not have the same rights within the client to look up/invoke the reader to render the program.  Makes sense?  Have you put the Full Trust security attribute on the browser?   This is jsut a guess.